# how can i make this RFID module work

Tags: arduino, rfid

how can i make this RFID module work, i dont have diagram and i cant find this type of module in the internet also.
and what kind of library would i used?

[RFID module pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sj0Ki.jpg)

Comment: What can you see on the central chip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your module is a cheap 125 kHz RFID module that supports a `Serial` interface and also provides Wiegand output. You can communicate with it by merely connecting 'V' to 5V, 'G' to GND, and 'TX' to a SoftwareSerial RX pin. It'll spit out the serial number of your RFID tag accompanied with a checksum. Download the library [here](https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/RFID_Library), follow their instructions and run the basic example to scan a card.